# CSS Multiple Overlays resulting in zero height

Tags: html, css, overlay

**TLDR**
The divs are not taking auto (based on content) height, rather height is always 0 : [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEBsz)

---

I have a container div, I am trying to layer the second child above the first child using the absolute positioning.

As long as, the container has one child, it works fine, with more than one child the container along with children give zero height. **It works when I specify explicit heights. Is there a way to get it to work otherwise?**

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="overlay first"></div>
  <div class="overlay second">
    Overlay text
  </div>
</div>


.cont {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #687999;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.first {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.second {
  color: black;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you have to explicitly set a height for the parent **or** have at least one non-positioned child that has height. Unfortunately, what you are **apparently** trying to do is not possible. Think about it..how can you overlay something that has no height...it's not logical.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were meant to use `background-color: black` for your class .second.

**Have a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cstBe**

Comment: Actually, I was experimenting with that codepen and I had specified height to `.cont`, but I want it work without explicit height.